Is there a QuickScript.Net attribute to obtain a list of all the objects inside a container?
Just like you can enter:
Me.Container
Is there a way to obtain a list of all objects contained inside a container or object?
I'm trying to use a for loop to modify an attribute on all the child objects inside the container.

To the best of my knowledge, no there isn't an easy way to do that. You could potentially script something if you're wanting to query the galaxy database, or I think there's options if you've implemented Base Template Library, but natively I don't think so. Use Object Viewer to poke around the Container object and see if there's a property you could work off of, but I didn't see anything on my Galaxy

Me.Engine.Objects contain list of objects within the engine, so you have to do some filtering based on area / container.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Yes, there is.
for each s in MyEngine.Engine.Objects[]

Will cycle through all the objects in that specific engine for example.
Thereafter you can use something like:
if StringInString(s, "Machine", 1, 0) > 0 then

to check for specific objects.
Or other kinds of filtering.
